# Passing updated objects in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, ssis, ssms

At my job I've faced with following problem: sql or t-sql is really slow if we gonna manipulate with big numbers of data. I mean millions or billions rows and this ways (when you need use while inside while or recursion in recursion) SSMS (MS SQL) doesn't work fast (I also tried indexes and many others sql tips). I know that other programming languages works faster this way- now I'm trying to pass data from sql to C# (using SSIS sql and script tasks) or to Java (NetBeans). Could you please help me and share any features about how to pass object variable, which had been updated in SSIS script tasks to sql task (insert). I'm not knew in SSIS, but 70% of my experiance there is building DWH, I've used script task just for messege box last time.

I know that firsly we need to get our array (table) from sql in sql task and pass it to object varialbe.
Second step is to update data in script task.
Third is to get object from step 2 and insert into sql updated data.
Could you please help me with 2nd and 3rd steps? How to create output variable in C# script task (for example we have table with 1 column and want to increment all values to 1) and move to the next SSIS block?

I want to describe this example more:

1. We have table with 1 column named i and value 0;
2. We pass value from table in full result set (sql task);
3. How to make changes in c# script task and return new value of variable that we got from previous step?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to pass table as full result set from sql task to script task. In script task I want to manipulate data of object variable and the move updated object (table columns) to another sql task. I know how make 1st step, but don't know how move updated object variable from script task to another sql task in SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable of type Object.  Use a data flow task to send your data into your destination object variable and pass that variable to your script task.  The object can then be cast to DataTable type in the script task like so:

```
var data = (DataTable)Dts.Variables["User::MyHugeDataSet"].Value;
```

Hope this helps, but I strongly suggest you revisit your requirements and see if there is a set based way of accomplishing this in SQL.  Doing what you are trying to do here is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Sql is too slow when we working with big arrays in while condition. I meant updated data in c# script task and then insert values in sql task in construction "insert into db.dbo.table values (?, ?, ? etc)" from c# scripts component. Just wanted to realise it in SSIS.